# What kind of font I should use for TextView that can support all languages?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, android-fonts

I have a textView that can display a Text in any languages ( End-users input the text).

I am wondering that what font I should use?

In this article: http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-roboto-noto

Google says:

> To support all languages worldwide, Google recommends using Roboto for
>   languages that use the Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic scripts and Noto for
>   all other languages.

If I understand it correctly. There is no single font file (Roboto|Noto) can support all languages.

Anyone know what font I can use? Should default font (Android decides) be a choice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android already does this for you. Read the paragraph before that cited paragraph:

> Since the Ice Cream Sandwich release, Roboto has been the standard
>   typeface on Android. **Since Froyo, Noto has been the standard typeface
>   on Android for all languages not covered by Roboto.**

So don't change the font/typeface used and you will be fine.

Remember that, that design site is not only for android, but also for the web, Chrome os etc as well for Google's unified/cross platform design, hence the wording.

Comment: So you mean: An textView can display a text in any languages - Latin, Greek, Cyrillic, other languages (Entered by end-users) by default? Does this work in all Android devices (Anroid 4+) of all manufactures?

Comment: "Any" and "all" are strong words :) No promises. But yes, within any limits of those fonts, yes it should and usually does.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in trying different fonts than Roboto or Noto, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font#List_of_Unicode_fonts displays a list of some fonts along with a number for each category/language on characters it supports. The "GNU Unifont" font appears to be a good choice.